# r apply a list of logical matrices to a list of matrices

Tags: r, list, matrix, indexing

I have a list of symmetrical matrices that I want to use only the lower triangle for:

```
my_list

$m1
     V1   V2   V3   V4   V5
[1,] 1.00 0.22 0.27 0.30 0.35
[2,] 0.22 1.00 0.33 0.35 0.15
[3,] 0.27 0.33 1.00 0.44 0.44
[4,] 0.30 0.35 0.44 1.00 0.44
[5,] 0.35 0.15 0.44 0.44 1.00

$m2
     V1   V2   V3   V4   V5
[1,] 1.00 0.16 0.34 0.26 0.23
[2,] 0.16 1.00 0.33 0.20 0.21
[3,] 0.34 0.33 1.00 0.34 0.44
[4,] 0.26 0.20 0.34 1.00 0.18
[5,] 0.23 0.21 0.44 0.18 1.00`
```

To get the lower triangle, I first made a list of logical matrixes using

```
lowtri <- lapply(DATA_RSAbrain,lower.tri)

      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[5,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[5,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

I want to apply this list of logical matrices to get a list of vectors with values from the lower triangle (the "TRUEs").

I've tried multiple ways, e.g.

```
my_list[lowtri]
```

But I haven't been able to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider bypassing generating the logical matrices, and apply `lower.tri()` on your list:

```
new_list <- lapply(my_list, function(x) x[lower.tri(x)])
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `Map` to extract the values of each of the `matrix` based on the corresponding logical `matrix` in 'lowtri' `list`

```
Map(`[`, my_list, lowtri)
```

---

Or using `map2` from `purrr`

```
library(tidyverse)
map2(my_list, lowtri, `[`)
```